# renaming files based on matched pattern in another file

Tags: bash, rename

I have a list of files:

```
out_CCGCGGTT+CTAGCGCT_R1.fq.gz
out_TTATAACC+TCGATATC_R2.fq.gz
out_GGACTTGG+CGTCTGCG_R1.fq.gz
out_AAGTCCAA+TACTCATA_R2.fq.gz
...
```

the adaptor IDs (between the two underscores, like AACGTTCC+AGTACTCC, AACGTTCC+AGTACTCC) match with the first column of ID.file.txt

```
head ID.file.txt:
CCGCGGTT+CTAGCGCT   NHL_332_N
TTATAACC+TCGATATC   NHL_333_T
GGACTTGG+CGTCTGCG   NHL_334_T
AAGTCCAA+TACTCATA   NHL_335_T
ATCCACTG+ACGCACCT   NHL_336_N
GCTTGTCA+GTATGTTC   NHL_337_N
CAAGCTAG+CGCTATGT   NHL_338_N
TGGATCGA+TATCGCAC   NHL_339_T
...
```

I want to rename the files and replace the adaptor IDs with the real ID (second column of the ID file) if they match and also remove "out" from the beginning.

So my final file names, example:

```
NHL_332_N_R1.fq.gz
NHL_333_T_R2.fq.gz
NHL_334_T_R1.fq.gz
NHL_335_T_R2.fq.gz
```

is there any way to do it in bash?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Different systems have different tools and different versions of the same tools so we need to know what you are using to know what will work for you. Please [edit] your question and tell us your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Perl's script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %h;
open(my $id_file, '<', 'ID.file.txt') or die "$!";
while (<$id_file>) {
    chomp;
    my ($pid, $id) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
    $h{$pid} = $id;
}
close($id_file);

foreach my $file (glob('*.fq.gz')) {
    if ($file =~ /^out_(.+)_R(\d)\.fq\.gz$/) {
        my $pid = $1;
        my $read_num = $2;
        my $id = $h{$pid};
        if ($id) {
            my $new = "${id}_R${read_num}.fq.gz";
            rename($file, $new) or die "$!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
typeset -A map=( $(<ID.file.txt) )
zmv -n '(out_)(*)(_R<->.fq.gz)' '${map[$2]-$1$2}$3'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.